# I want to ORDER BY the nearest number

Tags: php, mysql

```
database name:property
column name  :details
row 1        :house 5000
row 2        :land 25000
row 3        :bungalow 10000
row 4        :shop 15000
row 5        :godown 20000
row 6        :30000
row 7        :40000
```

the column has contains text and number. i want to sort them by the nearest number. for example if i want sort by $number=10000. the result i need like this below.

```
1) bungalow 10000
2) shop 15000
3) house 5000
4) godown 20000
5) land 25000
6) 30000
7) 40000
```

any one can help me some code like this.

```
$sql="select * from property ORDER BY abs(details-$number)";
```

Comment: Why does `house 5000` go after `shop 15000` and before `godown 20000`?

Comment: So, mathematically, you're doing right thing since distance between `x` and `y` is `|x-y|` (i.e. `ABS()` in MySQL). What error are you getting? What result are you getting?

Comment: Does adding the result to the select clause and naming it solves this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM property
 ORDER BY ABS(SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', -1) * 1 - 10000), details
```

Output:

```
|        DETAILS |
|----------------|
| bungalow 10000 |
|     house 5000 |
|     shop 15000 |
|   godown 20000 |
|     land 25000 |
|          30000 |
|          40000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f649c8/3)** demo

In php it will look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT *
  FROM property
 ORDER BY ABS(SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', -1) * 1 - $number), details";
```

**Note:** consider to use **[prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of interpolating query strings.

Comment: @Wes You may consider this as pseudo code to keep it more clear for OP which uses php. Other than that do you have any other reasons for down voting?

Comment: @user3247433 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a mysql question and you want the answer in pure SQL, you first want a proper table.  I would start with the following:

```
mysql> show create table property;
...
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `type` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Now let's create the data:

```
mysql> insert into property values ('home', 5000);
mysql> insert into property values ('land', 25000);
mysql> insert into property values ('bungalow', 10000);
mysql> insert into property values ('shop', 15000);
mysql> insert into property values ('godown', 20000);
mysql> insert into property values (NULL, 30000);
mysql> insert into property values (NULL, 40000);
```

Now let's define the variable we use in mysql to represent the origin:

```
mysql> set @origin = 10000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

You can write your pure sql statement as such:

```
mysql> select *, abs(value - @origin) distance
         from property
     order by 3 asc, 2 desc;
+----------+-------+----------+
| type     | value | distance |
+----------+-------+----------+
| bungalow | 10000 |        0 |
| shop     | 15000 |     5000 |
| home     |  5000 |     5000 |
| godown   | 20000 |    10000 |
| land     | 25000 |    15000 |
| NULL     | 30000 |    20000 |
| NULL     | 40000 |    30000 |
+----------+-------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```